# how to align listview items top left?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to align list view items at the top left, but it aligns them in the center. I tried this with another widget, it works fine, but with the listview, it doesn't.

here is my code

```
 Container(
                              height: height * 30,
//                              color: Colors.grey[400],
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                itemBuilder: (context, i) => ReviewItem(
                                  review: book.reviews[i]['review'],
                                  date: book.reviews[i]['date'],
                                ),
                                itemCount: book.reviews.length,
                              ),
                            ),
```

this is the review item

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          timeago.format(DateTime.parse(date)),
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.copyWith(
              fontSize: width * kFont12Ratio, color: Colors.grey[500]),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: height * 0.5),
        Text(review),
        Divider(),
      ],
    );
```

[image: this is what i am getting]

[image: this is what I am expecting]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, ListView will automatically pad the list's scrollable extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's padding. In other words, if you put a widget before the ListView, you should wrap the ListView with a `MediaQuery.removePadding` widget (with `removeTop: true`). Like so:

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
  context: context,
  removeTop: true,
  child: ListView.builder(...),
);
```

Answer (score 4):

I achieved that by adding padding inside the listview builder

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use padding instead
Or use Stack with Position (top:0,left:0)
Or use Align( )